# $(this).is(':checkbox') prevents checking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a on click function bound to three elements, the first just triggers it checking two radio buttons and declaring a variable with the checked value, the second are checkboxes and declares variables with the value of those and the third element are the pagination links to declare and assign the page to send it to php.

I tried adding `$(this).prop('checked', true);` but the checkboxes are not checked when clicked (I don't know whats preventing them):

```
$('body').on('click', '.click, :checkbox, .pag_link', function()
{
    // search, filters and change page buttons

    if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
        var use = $('#res_prop').val(); // 1
    }
    else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
        var use = $('#com_prop').val(); // 0
    }
    else {
        $('p.error').show();
        die();
    }

    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
        // not needed or it won't uncheck -> $(this).prop('checked', true);
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter1' || $('.filter1').is(':checked')) {
            var type = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
        } else var type = null;
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter2' || $('.filter2').is(':checked')) {
            var status = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
        } else var status = null;
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter3' || $('.filter3').is(':checked')) {
            var bhk = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
        } else var bhk = null;
    }
    else {
        var type = status = bhk = null;
    }

    if ($(this).is('.pag_link')) {
        if ($(this).text() == '«')
            var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) - 1);
        else if ($(this).text() == '»')
            var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) + 1);
        else
            var page = parseInt($(this).text());
    }
    else {
        var page = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/search',
        data: {
            'do': getUrlParameter('do'),
            'use': use,
            'type': type,
            'status': status,
            'bhk': bhk,
            'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
            'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val(),
            'page': page
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if ($( '#search' ).is(':visible'))
            $( '#search' ).hide();

        if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#scroll-to-list' ).replaceWith( new_content );
        }
        else {
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#search-filters, #scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#results' ).html( new_content );
        }

        $( 'html, body' ).animate({
            scrollTop: $( '#scroll-to-list' ).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    //return false;
});
```

Sorry I need to learn to simplify the code.

Code snippet:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.click, :checkbox, .pag_link', function() { // search, filters and change page buttons

  if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var use = $('#res_prop').val();
  } else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var use = $('#com_prop').val();
  }

  if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
    //$(this).prop('checked', true); // still not checking them
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter1' || $('.filter1').is(':checked')) {
      var type = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var type = null;
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter2' || $('.filter2').is(':checked')) {
      var status = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var status = null;
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter3' || $('.filter3').is(':checked')) {
      var bhk = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var bhk = null;
  } else {
    var type = status = bhk = null;
  }

  if ($(this).is('.pag_link')) {
    if ($(this).text() == '«')
      var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) - 1);
    else if ($(this).text() == '»')
      var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) + 1);
    else
      var page = parseInt($(this).text());
  } else {
    var page = 1;
  }

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/search',
    data: {
      'do': 'abc',
      'use': use,
      'type': type,
      'status': status,
      'bhk': bhk,
      'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
      'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val(),
      'page': page
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    if ($('#search').is(':visible'))
      $('#search').hide();

    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
      var new_content = $(data).find('#scroll-to-list');
      $('#scroll-to-list').replaceWith(new_content);
    } else {
      var new_content = $(data).find('#search-filters, #scroll-to-list');
      $('#results').html(new_content);
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#scroll-to-list').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand" value="1">
    <label for="brand"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_1'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand1" value="2">
    <label for="brand1"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_2'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand2" value="3">
    <label for="brand2"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_3'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand3" value="4" />
    <label for="brand3"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_4'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand4" value="5">
    <label for="brand4"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_5'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand5" value="6">
    <label for="brand5"><span></span><?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_6'); ?></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have JS fiddle or actual example?

Comment: Yes, I just added it.

Comment: if you are using jquery below 1.5 then instead of prop try attr() -> `$(this).attr('checked', true)`

Comment: I'm using the last version.

Comment: check the console for errors. that may help here!

Comment: The problem is with the `return false` statement of your code. If you remove that line, it will definitely work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/h25ruso1/1/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yes thanks it's checking them now but they are automatically unchecked and it shouldn't, the only div changing is `#scroll-to-list`, the checkboxes are inside `#search-filters`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `return false` statement of your code. Since you have attached the event to the parent element(`body`), the return false statement will act as event.preventDefault(). Ie,   event handler prevents default behavior, in your case, it is checking of the checkbox.

Working snippet:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.click, :checkbox, .pag_link', function() { // search, filters and change page buttons

  if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var use = $('#res_prop').val();
  } else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
    var use = $('#com_prop').val();
  }

  if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {

    $(this).prop('checked', true); // still not checking them

    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter1' || $('.filter1').is(':checked')) {
      var type = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var type = null;
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter2' || $('.filter2').is(':checked')) {
      var status = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var status = null;
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'filter3' || $('.filter3').is(':checked')) {
      var bhk = $(this).val(); // maybe should be an array
    } else var bhk = null;
  } else {
    var type = status = bhk = null;
  }

  if ($(this).is('.pag_link')) {
    if ($(this).text() == '«') var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) - 1);
    else if ($(this).text() == '»') var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) + 1);
    else var page = parseInt($(this).text());
  } else {
    var page = 1;
  }

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/search',
    data: {
      'do': 'abc',
      'use': use,
      'type': type,
      'status': status,
      'bhk': bhk,
      'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
      'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val(),
      'page': page
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    if ($('#search').is(':visible')) $('#search').hide();

    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
      var new_content = $(data).find('#scroll-to-list');
      $('#scroll-to-list').replaceWith(new_content);
    } else {
      var new_content = $(data).find('#search-filters, #scroll-to-list');
      $('#results').html(new_content);
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#scroll-to-list').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  //  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand" value="1">
    <label for="brand"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_1'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand1" value="2">
    <label for="brand1"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_2'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand2" value="3">
    <label for="brand2"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_3'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand3" value="4" />
    <label for="brand3"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_4'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand4" value="5">
    <label for="brand4"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_5'); ?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="brand5" value="6">
    <label for="brand5"><span></span>
            <?php echo $lang->getW('prop_type_6'); ?></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can check if checkbox is checked or not:

```
<script>
    if($("input#yourId").attr("checked" , true)) {
        //Doing some functions
    }
</script>
```

And I think you should remove `return false` in your code for working better.